# Android: iText lib:parse PDF to String

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I try to parse local PDF on my Smartphone with iText:

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;


public class CodeArchiva extends ActionBarActivity {





        /** The original PDF that will be parsed. */
        public static final String PREFACE = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "PDF-Cache/PDF/VP.pdf");

        public static final String RESULT="";

        public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            reader.close();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
            new CodeArchiva().parsePdf(PREFACE, RESULT);
            Log.d("Code:", RESULT);
        }
    }
```

The PDF should be "read"/parsed to a String. There ist no Error, but also no Log with my Parsed PDF.

I think this is the only iText Log:

> 29100-29100/APP E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(210)] Failed
>   to locate a binder for interface:
>   autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver requested by:  exposed by:  via
>   InterfaceProviderSpec "navigation:frame".
>
> ```
>                                                            InterfaceRegistry(navigation:frame):
> ```
>
> Owned by:
>   @ run as:
>
> Providing:
>
> Requiring:
>
> Bound to:
>   @ run as:
>
> Providing:
>
> Requiring:
>
> Binders registered for:
>                                                                  autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver
>                                                                     blink::mojom::MediaSessionService
>                                                                     blink::mojom::PermissionService
>                                                                     blink::mojom::PresentationService
>                                                                     blink::mojom::ShapeDetection
>                                                                     blink::mojom::WebBluetoothService
>                                                                     blink::mojom::WebSocket
>                                                                     device::VibrationManager
>                                                                     device::mojom::GeolocationService
>                                                                     device::mojom::VRService
>                                                                     device::mojom::WakeLockService
>                                                                     device::nfc::mojom::NFC
>                                                                     media::mojom::InterfaceFactory
>                                                                     mojom::MediaDevicesDispatcherHost
>                                                                     web_restrictions::mojom::WebRestrictions
>
> All interfaces exposed.

It would be nice if you can help me. It helps me and the other readers if you can explain it by an example.

Sourcecode: https://github.com/itext/i5js-book/blob/develop/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted2.java

Comment: Please update your link. iText no longer uses SourceForge. iText sources are on GitHub: https://github.com/itext. More specifically, that example is now at https://github.com/itext/i5js-book/blob/develop/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted2.java. EDIT: I made the edit myself already.

Comment: Can you also edit your log? It is indented very far to the right, that makes it hard to read.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for editing. I used already the Code from github and the lib, but it didn´t work

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I think that the log dont show the problem. Maybe the code dont get called by open the Android Activity. Or the code work but not in my way. (My Goal: extract PDF to String [Android]) but the example didnt work for Android.

Comment: Your log doesn't show in the StackOverflow Android app.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I did a next try and find out, that the action send no log information. If i call the activity nothing got logged. So i think, that the Code is wrong / got not called

Comment: No, I mean here on Stack Overflow. They have an Android app. In that app, your code is so far to the right that I have to scroll out of my way.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i hope that this is now fixed

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thats great, i hope that i now got help!